# grails : how to validate single field in command object

Tags: validation, grails

I want to manually validate field in command object

I know I can get field's max value (and min) with this:

```
MyDomain.constraints.myField.getAppliedConstraint('max').maxValue
```

How can I execute 'validate' command on 'myField' and get errors object ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at the [grails docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/validate.html).

You could use the `validate()` method on a defined list of properties:

```
if(!yourObject.validate(['myField'])) {
    yourObject.errors.each { 
        println it
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I do not have domain object instance available in command object

Comment: You could define contraints within your `CommandObject` and validate the needed property of your `CommandObject` the same way you would validate your domain instances - look [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#commandObjects).

Comment: Thanks aiolos! But I would like to validate against constraints that are defined in a domain and do validation in command object. I have to do this in many places and I don't want to copy same constraints values in different command objects.

Comment: Use [constraint sharing](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/Usage.html) between the `domain` and the `command object`.

Comment: Aiolos, You saved my day. Thank you ! I accepted the original answer